# AngularJS on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I'm new AngularJS, I'm trying to test the most basic form using AngularJS in JSFiddle. I'm not sure if I forget to configure anything in JSFiddle, but it is not working and it should.

I followed a basic sample from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_forms.asp).

I also include the CDN from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js).

Here is the Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
});
```

Link to my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/tth4guev/

---

## Settings

[image]

---

## include

[image]

---

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: did the answer help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things missing

(i) You need to add ng-app directive as follows,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
```

(ii) Change the angular.js script version above 1.1 to use without a global controller, and change load type as **`No wrap in <head>`**

[image]

[`WORKING FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/0d85ntt9/)

Answer (score 1):

I see, you did not add a name to your controller,and Angular App but in the JS you are accessing 'formctrl'. Go ahead and add a div around the form and add a ng-app='myApp' and a ng-controller='form-ctrl' to your form and it should work.

Comment: I think I forgot this line completely. 
`<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the form tag in a `div` tag with `ng-app` attribute. Your `h1` tag should be encapsulated within the `div` tag as well...

Here's a working example:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <form>
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
  </form>
  <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's the thing I saw with your code:
You need to add the name of the App and the controller to the div.

Also you are repeating the name of the *person* in both fields, if you wish you can make an **object** with the person information to access each of his data fields:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
   <form>
      Email: <input type="text" ng-model="person.firstname" />
      Password: <input type="text" ng-model="person.password" />
   </form>

   <h1>You entered: {{ person.firstname }}</h1>
</div>

<script>
   var myApp = angular
       .module("myApp",[])
       .controller("formCtrl", function($scope) {
          //here's the object called "person":
          var person = {
             firstname: "John",
             password: "password"
          };

          $scope.person = person;
   });
</script>
```